# SunRingle ratchet rings

Tags: hub

I have a used Stan's NoTubes Neo hub and would like to replace the ratchet ring and pawls. These were once available but are now out of stock everywhere.

Since these hubs, like most hubs these days, are made in Taiwan I was hoping to find the same ring with a different label.

Anybody know what the outside diameter (and thread pitch) is on 30T and 36tooth  SunRingle ratchet rings?

Answer (score 3):

Here are [springs and pawls](https://www.notubes.com/stan-s-3-30-series-hub-spring-and-pawl-kit). They don't have anything called "ratchet ring"
Stan's No Tubes has them in stock.

They also [sell a ki](https://www.notubes.com/kit-neo-spring-and-pawl-6pc)t with a retaining ring that holds the pawls in place.

[image]